# Facebook Liking do not work like in example iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook

Im trying to figure out why my code doesn't work despite i based my code on example which works correctly.
Here is code of my class:

```
#import "FBClass.h"
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "FacebookLikeView.h"


@interface FBClass () <FacebookLikeViewDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) Facebook *facebook;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FacebookLikeView *facebookLikeView;

@end

@implementation FBClass

@synthesize facebookLikeView = facebookLikeView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:120/255.0f green:120/255.0f blue:120/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        self.view.backgroundColor = color;

         self.facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"7592374973434" andDelegate:self];

          UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         myButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
         [myButton sizeToFit];
         [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myCustomFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



        UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        lbl1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lbl1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        lbl1.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        lbl1.text= @"textoadkow";


        self.facebookLikeView = [[FacebookLikeView alloc] init];
      //  [facebookLikeView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

           [lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(35, 60, 400, 100)];
            lbl1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];


            myButton.frame = CGRectMake(85, 40, 150, 50);
            myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:35];
            [myButton setTitle:@"Tap" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [facebookLikeView setFrame:CGRectMake(85, 150, 150, 50)];

        [self.view addSubview:lbl1];
        [self.view addSubview:myButton];
     [self.view addSubview:facebookLikeView];


        self.facebookLikeView.href = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/pages/pageName/id"];
        self.facebookLikeView.layout = @"button_count";
        self.facebookLikeView.showFaces = NO;
        self.facebookLikeView.alpha = 0;
        [self.facebookLikeView load];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark FBSessionDelegate

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    self.facebookLikeView.alpha = 1;
    [self.facebookLikeView load];
}

- (void)fbDidLogout {
    self.facebookLikeView.alpha = 1;
    [self.facebookLikeView load];
}
```

While "[This](https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView)" is working correctly. I based on "[Link](https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView/blob/master/FacebookLikeViewDemo/FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController.m)" Only thing i changed is that i create my view programmatically. The problem is that nothing appears in created View.

Where is problem?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see if your view creation code is even being called? I would try moving all of that initialisation to `viewDidLoad` - well, actually I would just use Image Builder.

Comment: Code works becouse i can see button and Label, I tried to move all to viewDidLoad, but it dosen't make it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line -

```
self.facebookLikeView.alpha = 0;
```

makes the control invisible (Sets the alpha channel to 0).

Change it to

```
self.facebookLikeView.alpha = 1.0;
```

and your control should appear.  I don't know why that line is in the sample code.  I can only assume that using the control from the xib file resets the alpha somehow.

The demo code is also missing

```
self.facebookLikeView.delegate=self;
```

Without this your delegate methods won't fire

Comment: I replaced as you said, i called "self.facebookLikeView = [[FacebookLikeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 150, 150, 50)];"
But still nothing appears